# How can I improve the for loop performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, loops, for-loop

When belgeList.length = 200, it completes the loop in 16 seconds. However, when I want to list more than 200, I expect more. How can i speed up this for loop?

```
internal DtResult documentCheckList(AksBelgeKontrolData[] belgeList, string dmUser = null)
{

    if ((dmUser == null) || (dmUser == "") || (CurrentDomain == "nvi.local"))
        dmUser = "MERNIS\\************";
    
    
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < belgeList.Length; i++)
    {
        var belgeData = belgeList[i];
        var anaBelgeTur = belgeData.AnaBelgeTur;

        if (anaBelgeTur == AnaBelgeTur.AksYeniBelge)
        {
            belgeList[i].BelgeVar = GdAksYeniQueries.AksBelgeKontrolu(belgeData, dmUser);
        }
        else if (anaBelgeTur == AnaBelgeTur.TckkYeniBelge)
        {
            belgeList[i].BelgeVar = GdTckkYeniQueries.TckkBelgeKontrolu(belgeData, dmUser);
        }
        //else if (anaBelgeTur == AnaBelgeTur.MernisBelge)
        //{
        //    belgeList[i].BelgeVar = GdMernisQueries.MernisBelgeKontrolu(belgeData, dmUser);
        //}
    }

    DtResult result = new DtResult { ResultState = DtResultState.Ok };
  
    result.BelgeKontrolListesi = belgeList;
    sw.Stop();
    var test = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Please rewrite the name of function to English (at least here on SO) so that people can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

From what i can conclude you are initiating queries to external sources (Database or API, etc.) inside the loop (`GdAksYeniQueries`, `GdTckkYeniQueries`).
As a general consideration you should avoid making queries to external sources in a loop for each single element.
Rather, make one query in **batch mode** before the loop. Save the data in-memory. Then iterate on the elements and process them against the already fetched data.

If it is not appropriate to fetch all the data in one query, still implement an iterative solution which will fetch data based on a configurable batch size.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the for loop, you can consider using parallel processing techniques to distribute the workload across multiple threads or processors. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to utilize parallel processing using Parallel.For:

```cs
internal DtResult documentCheckList(AksBelgeKontrolData[] belgeList, string dmUser = null)
{
    if ((dmUser == null) || (dmUser == "") || (CurrentDomain == "nvi.local"))
        dmUser = "MERNIS\\************";

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    // Use Parallel.For to process the loop in parallel
    Parallel.For(0, belgeList.Length, i =>
    {
        var belgeData = belgeList[i];
        var anaBelgeTur = belgeData.AnaBelgeTur;

        if (anaBelgeTur == AnaBelgeTur.AksYeniBelge)
        {
            belgeList[i].BelgeVar = GdAksYeniQueries.AksBelgeKontrolu(belgeData, dmUser);
        }
        else if (anaBelgeTur == AnaBelgeTur.TckkYeniBelge)
        {
            belgeList[i].BelgeVar = GdTckkYeniQueries.TckkBelgeKontrolu(belgeData, dmUser);
        }
        //else if (anaBelgeTur == AnaBelgeTur.MernisBelge)
        //{
        //    belgeList[i].BelgeVar = GdMernisQueries.MernisBelgeKontrolu(belgeData, dmUser);
        //}
    });

    DtResult result = new DtResult { ResultState = DtResultState.Ok };
    result.BelgeKontrolListesi = belgeList;
    sw.Stop();
    var test = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Any concurrent technique introduces a bunch of potential problems with thread safety. So while sometimes useful, I would not advice using parallel.For before checking other possible improvements first, and only then with a warning about the dangers.